# ReferenceError with passing variable into function

Tags: javascript, react-native, callback

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I don't know how to word my question well enough to search for it:

When I try to run this snippet of code:

```
var tempList = [];
var followingArr = [];
response.data.forEach(async (following, i) => {
    var numFollowers = 0;
    axios.get(following.followers_url)
        .then(async (response) => {
            numFollowers = response.length;
            followingArr.push({key: following.name, numFollowers: numFollowers});
            tempList.push({key: following.name, numFollowers: numFollowers, pic: this.state.followingPics[i]});
         })
         .catch((error) => {
             console.log(error);
         });
});
```

I keep getting the error `Error fetching following: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: following`. I'm guessing this is because I need to pass the variable following into my call to `axios.get` somehow, but I'm not exactly sure how to.

Comment: The code above won't produce that error, `following` is clearly in-scope everywhere it's used. The problem must be in code you haven't shown.

Comment: It's not the error you're having, but I recommend you read up on [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), because you're using them incorrectly above. It makes no sense to pass an `async` function into `forEach`, nor to pass one as a promise `then` callback. And it rarely makes sense to use one if you never use `await` within it.

Comment: Also -> `response.data.forEach(async`  here `async` is meaningless.  Also all items in following are going to execute in parallel.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I jumped to conclusions thinking it was something to do with callbacks. I'll get rid of the `async` keyword too. Thank you!